# Office tools and VLC in Redhat linux 7

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am new in rhel, anyone can tell me how to install office tools (.xls, .docx) in Redhat Linux 7 and other programs like VLC media player in GUI mode.

Comment: Read the [Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Installing.html)

Comment: Can you provide some context for your question?  Installing basic software that is included in the repository is one of the most fundamental operations.  Are you totally new to Linux, picked RHEL, and don't know where to start, or do you have some familiarity but are running into a particular problem?  Can you focus the question a little on the specifics of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a menu option somewhere in your desktop environment called something like `Add/remove software` or `package manager`.

If you cannot find such an option, open any terminal emulator inside X-Window environment and run: `pirut` and enter your root password

If `pirut` is not yet installed, you need to install it entering following command as root: `yum install pirut` (To install it from a normal user session, try `sudo yum install pirut` (enter your user password) and `su -c yum install pirut` (enter root password) - one of those should work)

Working with the package manager should be pretty self-explanatory, however fedora has a [quick guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Tools/pirut) on it if you need it.

Installing packages (including `pirut` itself) requires working internet connection. Some packages may also be included on your distribution DVD.